# Last visited pages in site

Tags: php, joomla

I have one script where am trying to display in a website block The LATEST ARTICLES VISITED BY THE CURRENT USER.
The user can be anonymous or a member.
The articles are in table like [ id_art, intro, text]

So when the visitor X visit a page, i would like to put in the bloc the visited page.

Comment: Please include some code, SO users cannot guess what you have already. Presumably you want some solution for Joomla, you have failed to mention this at all in your question, you have just tagged it as Joomla

Answer (score 3):

Create a table on the form:

```
id, tstamp, art_id (key=[id, tstamp, art_id], index=[id, tstamp])
```

Whenever a user requests an article, add a row with article ID and timestamp. For the ID you can use the user ID for members or an auto-generated ID (persisted in a (session) cookie).

The list is then generated by extracting the latest `N` records in the table based on the (user/auto) `id`. (I.e., the *actual* list is generated by extracting `N` article titles and links based on a join on the IDs in the two tables.)

Credit goes to [silvo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295614/silvo) for the following point (see comments):

> ... you should do some periodic upkeep on your table to make sure you don't keep entries that are too old and irrelevant

(*Note: This is a generic solution. Nothing specific for Joomla / technology X / ... .*)

Comment: also worth mentioning that you should do some periodic upkeep on your table to make sure you don't keep entries that are too old and irrelevant...